# How to enable eager loading on a association in phpactiverecord?

Tags: eager-loading, phpactiverecord

I have an phpactiverecord Model "Category". This Model has a self-referential has_many association, and two has_one associations to another Model.

```
class Category extends Model {

    static $table_name = 'categories';

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'child_categories',
            'class_name' => 'Category',
            'primary_key' => 'categories_id',
            'foreign_key' => 'parent_id'
        )
    );



    static $has_one = array(
        array(
            'german_description',
            'class_name' => 'CategoryDescription',
            'primary_key' => 'categories_id',
            'foreign_key' => 'categories_id',
            'conditions' => 'language_id = 2'
        ),
        array(
            'english_description',
            'class_name' => 'CategoryDescription',
            'primary_key' => 'categories_id',
            'foreign_key' => 'categories_id',
            'conditions' => 'language_id = 1'
        )
    );

}
```

I can eager-load the has_one associations when I find Category, this works without any problem:

```
$category = ActiveRecord\Category::find(
    $category_id,
    array(
        'include' => array( 'german_description', 'english_description' )
    )
);
```

My problem is: When I iterate through all of a category's child-categories, and access the child-categories' has-one associations...

```
foreach( $category->child_categories as $child_category ){
    echo $child_category->german_description->categories_name;
}
```

..then a new query is run every time I do so, becauce the child-category's has-one associations are not eager loaded.

My question is: Is it possible to configure access a categories child-categories in a way that eager-loads the child-categories' has-one associations?